# .NET A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext".

This is my code in service:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<GetAllUsersDTO>> UsersById(Guid userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
try
{
    var Log = await _db.Users
                        .Include(x => x.University)
                        .Include(x => x.Fields)
                        .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToListAsync();

    var logsDTO = await Task.WhenAll(Log.Select(async x =>
    {
        var userInDb = await _db.Users.FindAsync((Guid)x.UserId); 
        var user = await _userService.GetDirectoryInformation(userInDb, cancellationToken);
        return new GetAllUsersDTO()
        {
            Description = x.Description,
            PostDate = x.PostDate,
            Id = x.Id,
            RecieveUserId = x.RecieveUserId,
            UniversityId = x.UniversityId,
            IsVisible = x.IsVisible,
            IsApproved = x.IsApproved,
            UserIdOpen = x.UserId,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            LogTitle = x.LogTitle,
            LogNr = x.LogNr,
            Email = user.Email,
        };
    }));

    return logsDTO.AsQueryable();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error=", ex.Message);
    throw;
}
}
```

This is how I'm injecting DataContext in this service:

```
private readonly DataContext _db;
public UserService(DataContext context) : base(context)
{
 _db = context;
}
```

Note: This service only works when Log list returns only one data. But when it returns more than one data, then it triggers the error.

I have tried configuring my dependency injection setup with ServiceLifetime.Scoped, and it looks like this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString"))
        ,ServiceLifetime.Scoped
    );
```

Comment: Is your UserService also injected as scoped ?

Comment: Hi @Scryper, yes it is.

Comment: It seems your issue is `Tasks.WhenAll`, as it is making multiple db calls at the same time, which is not possible as the context is the same for every request in that case as it is the same scope. But I do not understand why are you creating a task for each user you get from the first call ? It seems to be a call on an user id, so why could you get multiple users ? It also looks like you are doing a first get based on the id, the you do the same using Find. The first call doesn't return all the needed data ?
A solution would be to replace `Tasks.WhenAll` by a regular loop.

Comment: Hi @Scryper, actually yes. The problem was with the Tasks.Whenall... I guess copy-paste'ing code from online blogs is not the best solution lol. I got rid of the Tasks.WhenAll and now it works fine, except its a bit slow but I'll find a solution for it. Thanks for your help and efforts, much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't see Guru's answer :D, he was faster than me haha - You can actually copy-paste code from blogs, there is nothing wrong with that, but you have to question it. Does it suit my needs ? Why did the dev wrote his solution like that ? What do I have to adapt so that it answers my problem ? etc

Comment: Yes ofc but when you want to speed things up and finish all your daily tasks, sometimes you dont have time to do a lot of researches lol. But ye, at least we have a lot of resources where we can find solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: This service only works when Log list returns only one data. But when it returns more than one data, then it triggers the error.

`_db.Users.FindAsync` and potentially `GetDirectoryInformation` (it seems that it can use/uses database too) are the problem, the following:

```cs
var logsDTO = await Task.WhenAll(Log.Select(async x =>
{
    var userInDb = await _db.Users.FindAsync((Guid)x.UserId); 
    var user = await _userService.GetDirectoryInformation(userInDb, cancellationToken);
    // ...
}
```

Will schedule to execute as many tasks as there are logs in parallel. And EF Core database context is not supposed to be used from different threads simultaneously. That's it.

"Direct" workarounds:

1. Move fetching all the data in the initial query (`var Log = await _db.Users ...`) and remove usage of `_userService.GetDirectoryInformation` and the `Task.WhenAll(Log.Select` completely (I would argue that it the best course of action)
2. Create inner scope in every task and resolve context/`_userService` there

Also note, since you gathering logs for single user there is completely no reason to query for it in multiple threads. Even if for some reason you don't want to (or can't) just use `Select` to build the result, i.e.:

```cs
await _db.Users
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .Select(x => new GetAllUsersDTO
    {
        Description = x.Description,
        // ...
        UserName = x.User.UserName,
        Email = x.User.Email,
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then just fetch the data one time and that's it:

```cs
var Log = ...; // your original query
var userInDb = await _db.Users.FindAsync(userId); 
var user = await _userService.GetDirectoryInformation(userInDb, cancellationToken);
var result = Logs
    .Select(x => new GetAllUsersDTO {...}) // use user, no async/awaits in the select
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question @GuruStron.
I only changed the userInDb part and now it looks like this:

'var userInDb = _db.Users.Find((Guid)x.UserId); '.
This kinda solves my problem but idk it's kinda slowly. 
I wanted to remove the Task.WhenAll part but it throws another error saying: "Cannot implicitly convert type '"System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Models.GetAllUsersDTO>>"
to "System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.GetAllUsersDTO>"'

Comment: @leoxrmd  _"Cannot implicitly convert type"_ - looks like you are missing `await` somewhere. Again there is no need to query for the same info in the loop (even if `FindAsync`/`Find` should perform only a single query if tracking is enabled for the context).

Comment: I removed the Task.WhenAll part and this line solved me the convertion error: `return logsDTO.Select(async x => await x).Select(x => x.Result).AsQueryable();`. Idk how efficitien it is bcz I got it from gpt -.-. Again, I'm not liking the time all the query gets (around 10 seconds for 3 rows...), but I will try do improve it.
Thanks a lot @GuruStron.

Comment: @leoxrmd was glad to help! But based on the last comment it seems that you have misunderstood me a bit. There should not be at all async operations in the LINQ. See the last code snippet (it basically represents the whole method) - fetch user info BEFORE the LINQ and use the fetched `user` in the select.

Comment: thank you for the snippet as well. The thing is that somehow I need both userIndb and user objects inside the Linq because I should pass the LogsDTO.Email as a parameter to find the userInDb. And then pass the whole userInDb object inside the ...GetDirectoryInformation to compare this object with the ones I have in my ActiveDirectory and then get some extra infos from there as well. Its sort of a nested Linq query thats why somehow I "have" to go like this.

Comment: @leoxrmd you will use them the same way as you are using `_userService` - `.Select(x => new GetAllUsersDTO {Email = user.Email})`. No need to fetch them inside the LINQ. At least in the show code since it works with a single user.